# Compare row result and create new column

Tags: php, mysql

I will like to compare row results and create a new column when a specific column have the same fightID.

My query:

```
SELECT fight.fightdato, fight.fightID, players.name, 
       playersfight.playerid, playersfight.playerScore 
FROM fight 
INNER JOIN playersfight ON fight.fightID = playersfight.fightID 
INNER JOIN players ON playersfight.playerID = players.playersID
```

Result in php:

```
Fight   Fight Date  Player  PlayerScore
1       2014-10-10  Kevin   8
1       2014-10-10  Chris   4
2       2014-09-01  Kevin   8
2       2014-09-01  Eric    4
```

My wanted result:

```
Fight   Fight Date Player1 Result1 Player2 Result2
1       2014-10-10 Kevin   8       Chris   4
2       2014-09-01 Kevin   8       Eric    4
```

btw - I am new to php/mysql and programming in general

Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join `player` and `playerfight` tables once more.

Something like:

```
SELECT fight.fightID, fight.fightdato,
       p1.name as 'Player_1', pf1.playerid as 'PlayerID_1', pf1.playerScore as 'Result_1',
       p2.name as 'Player_2', pf2.playerid as 'PlayerID_2', pf2.playerScore as 'Result_2'          
FROM fight 
JOIN playersfight pf1 ON fight.fightID = pf1.fightID 
JOIN players p1       ON pf1.playerID  = p1.playersID
JOIN playersfight pf2 ON fight.fightID = pf2.fightID 
JOIN players p2       ON pf2.playerID  = p2.playersID
WHERE p1.playersID < p2.players2
```

The `WHERE` clause with `p1.playersID < p2.players2` condition excludes two cases that we don't want to have returned:

1. results with joined the same player twice in one row.
2. duplicates - for example for players with IDs `1` and `2` there would be returned the same fight twice with player IDs `(1,2)` and `(2,1)`. Now it will return only first permutation.

Comment: a semicolon was missing in the 2 line.
Thanks for the help :)